# VSCode include path property not working properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, include

**Backstory**

- I'm making a small game engine project for self-learning/ I'm using the Vulkan Graphics API alongside GLFW, which I compile with CMake. Everything works fine during compile-time, but when writing code inside VSCode it gives me false errors saying `cannot open source file "GLFW/glfw3.h"C/C++(1696)`. Even though if I go ahead and compile and include it into the main file it works as intended.
- I have tried restarting VSCode, restarting my computer, rebuilding CMake, and deleting the cache, tried using `<>` and `""` for including, and also using the VSCode suggestion of including it again in the CPP Properties file.
- Important note is that if I include the same code into my `main.cpp` file it all works fine, but the problem starts happening after I separating the code into separate files and try including GLFW.

**File Structure:**

```
+-> .vscode
| |
| +-> c_cpp_properties.json
| +-> settings.json
|
+-> bin
| |
| +-> Abyssal.exe
|
+-> build (CMake build files)
|
+-> src
| |
| +-> AbyssalWindow.h
| +-> main.cpp
|
+-> vendor (nothing inside this folder)
+-> CMakeLists.txt
```

```json
{
    "env": {
        "myDefaultIncludePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        ]
    },
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Windows",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "includePath": [
                "${myDefaultIncludePath}",
                "C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.0/Include",
                "C:/glfw-3.3.4/include"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

```cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

[image: Error Code]
[image: Working main file]
[image: C++ Properties File]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to use CMake as your buildsystem. I highly recommend keeping all your build settings in CMake then.

To convert your vscode config use:

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# declare global include directories used by all targets
# by using 'SYSTEM' many compilers will hide internal warnings
include_directories(SYSTEM
  "C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.0/Include"
  "C:/glfw-3.3.4/include"
)
```

Remove the corresponding settings from your vscode config and add your newly created header files to your call to `add_executable` so vscode gets the include directories right for the file.

Instead of include_directories you could prefer

```
target_include_directories(YOURTARGET ...)
```

to be more specific/"modern".

Comment: I actually have all of my buildsystem in the CMake file already. The problem I was having wasn't building the file or even a linker problem, it actually was just intellisense and including the header files from GLFW.